# Alert for aks pedning pods with azure monitor

Tags: azure, azure-aks, monitor

I need to set an alert for pending pods in aks with azure monitor. If the pending pod count reaches 10 for a duration of 1hr an alert should be triggered. I have tried some ways but not able to get through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to create the alert rules for the pod state is pending***

I have followed the below steps to create the alert rules

Have the AKS cluster and in that cluster I have created the alert rules as shown below

> ***Go-To*** → ***Portal*** → ***AKS-cluster*** → click on ***Alert*** → ***create new alert***

Selected the signal type as ***metrics*** and signal name as "***Number of pods by phase***"

[image]

In the condition page I have given the required fields

[image]

Used the dimensions to monitor the specific time series

[image]

To check alerts I have mentioned the look back period for 1 hour

[image]

I have enabled the recommended alert rules to send to email and click on review and create

[image]

I have created the example pod with pending state as shown below

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nodepod
  labels: 
    name: nodepod
spec:
  restartpolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: nodepod
    image: alpine
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
  nodeSelector:
    memoryOptimised: "yes"
```

Created the 10 pods and all my pods are in pending state

[image]

I have reached the 10 pending pods so I got the new alert with fired state

[image]

Below is my newly created alert for the pod state pending

[image]

Comment: But am not getting alert for image Pullback for pending i am able to get alerts is there a way to get alerts when there are pods with ImagePullBackOFF

Comment: @sysadmincrispy for image pullback the status is not pending, its status is ImagePullBack only, can you please raise a new question for imagepullback alerts So that I can address it in more detailed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74641431/aks-imagepullbackoff-not-getting-alerted-in-pending-pods-alert a new question has been raised for the same