# Aks ImagePullbackoff not getting alerted in Pending Pods Alert

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

I had set an alert in azure monitor for pending pods with kube pod phase set to pending in azure monitor. It only get alerted for pending pods and not ImagePullBack and CrashloopbackOFF . is there a way to get alerts for these too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom Alert for CrashLoopBackOff & ImagePullBackOff based on this Kusto Query:

```
KubePodInventory 
  | where PodStatus == 'Pending'
  | where ContainerStatusReason in ('ErrImagePull','ImagePullBackOff')
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. how to set the alert if the pending pod count reaches 10.